# Get reference to all instances of jquery ui widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-widget

I am writing a jquery UI widget that simply wraps the bootstrap popover plugin, In the widget you can pass in the option 'singular',
if this is passed in then it should call a function of all other instances of the plugin.

something like

```
$('#one').myWidget();
$('#two').myWidget();
$('#three').myWidget();
$('#four').myWidget();

$('#one').myWidget('show'); //stuff from widget one is now visible
$('#two').myWidget('show'); //stuff from widget one and two are now visible
$('#three').myWidget('show'); //stuff from widget one, two and three are now visible
$('#two').myWidget('hide'); //stuff from widget one and three are now visible
$('#four').myWidget('show', {singular:true}); //stuff from widget four is now visible
```

So, I imagine the show function looking like:

```
show: function(options){
    options = options || {};

    if(options.singular){
        var instances = '????'; // how do I get all instances?
        $.each(instances, function(i, o){
            o.myWidget('hide');
        });
    }

    this.element.popover('show');

}
```

So, question being, how would I get a reference to all elements that have the `myWidget` widget on them?

Comment: When you apply the plugin to those elements, then you're referencing them in `return this.each(function(){` in your instantiator. so just give them a class like, `myWidget` then you can do `$('.myWidget').each(`..

Comment: I agree- you can place a class on the widgets - then run through an each - I've seen coders place a data attribute - then run the each that way as their selector

Comment: That works, and what about getting a reference to all instances of a widget you don't control (e.g. UI's progressbar's etc)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `$(':ui-myWidget')` where `ui` is your widget's namespace.  It is slower than using a class selector like `$('.ui-myWidget')` so it is still good practice to add the class when your widget gets created.

jQuery UI does this for all there widgets so you could get each progressbar by either `$(':ui-progressbar')` or `$('.ui-progressbar')`.

[This blog post](http://www.boduch.ca/2011/07/jquery-ui-widget-selectors.html) explains thin in greater depth.