# Detect "hooked" DOM elements

Tags: javascript, object, jquery

So I have a set of jQuery plugins, really basic stuff, but I split the code into plugins because I don't like having a huge jQuery(document).ready() function where I store the entire application logic.

Each plugin has a "destructor", which is basically a function that I defined in the plugin prototype object. This function unbinds events used by the plugin, removes DOM elements that were added by the plugin etc.

Plugins are initialized like this:

```
$('.element').plugin();
```

Is there any way I can get all the elements that have my plugins attached to them, from another plugin which is supposed to replace the body HTML, so I can call the destructor function?

I was thinking to store each plugin instance inside a global array, then I can access that array from any plugin. But maybe there is a better way that doesn't use the global state?

Comment: When I build jquery widgets I use a [custom template that I wrote](https://github.com/zzzzBov/jQuery-widget.tmpl.js/blob/master/jqwt/jquery-widget.tmpl.js). It includes extending `$.expr[':']` so that the instantiated widgets can be selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a ready made method for it... but as a hack you can add a class to the target elements in your plugin and then use that class to get all elements with the widget initialized lke

```
$.fn.plugin = function(){
    this.addClass('my-plugin-class');
}
```

then to initialize

```
$(element).plugin()
```

to get all elements with the plugin

```
$('.my-plugin-class')....
```

But if it is a jQuery UI widget then you can use the selector `$(':ui-widgetname')`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204159/get-reference-to-all-instances-of-jquery-ui-widget)

Comment: That's actually a good idea, I could then select and destroy plugins that are hooked on elements from a certain area of the page, like `#main .plugin`

Answer (score 1):

[Arun P Johny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/114251/arun-p-johny) wrote the rigth idea -- just delete 'footprint' of your job by marking the affected DOM elements with some specific class name.

I want just add an idea. Plugins are the methods of the library and nothing more. If you need `the destroyer` for `constructor` -- just make another plugin for it:

```
$.fn.overture = function (){...};// construct
$.fn.crescendo = function (){...};// more construct
$.fn.quietFarewell = function (){...};// destructor for everything above

$(...).overture().crescendo().quietFarewell();
```